# Android app crashes right away after being downloaded from google play store

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, freshmvvm

I have created a Android app which runs perfectly fine when I debug it in Visual Studio 2019 on my Android phone.
But when I publish it to the Google Store and download it and run it on the same phone it crashes right away.

The stack trace is:

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, FreshTinyIoC.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, FreshTinyIoC.ResolveOptions options) <0x7e57beb580 + 0x006f0> in <035575fde1c44c4eaa00de78a4f3093f>:0
at FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, FreshTinyIoC.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, FreshTinyIoC.ResolveOptions options) <0x7e57be9354 + 0x00053> in <035575fde1c44c4eaa00de78a4f3093f>:0
at FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, FreshTinyIoC.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, FreshTinyIoC.ResolveOptions options) <0x7e57beade0 + 0x006ff> in <035575fde1c44c4eaa00de78a4f3093f>:0
at FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer.Resolve (System.Type resolveType) <0x7e57be85d4 + 0x00083> in <035575fde1c44c4eaa00de78a4f3093f>:0
at FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer.Resolve[ResolveType] () <0x7e57be8668 + 0x0003b> in <035575fde1c44c4eaa00de78a4f3093f>:0
at FreshMvvm.FreshTinyIOCBuiltIn.Resolve[ResolveType] () <0x7e57b810c0 + 0x00047> in <d2b205c381d14059b4260d7482e68c02>:0
at FreshMvvm.FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel[T] (System.Object initData) <0x7e57b80c90 + 0x00057> in <d2b205c381d14059b4260d7482e68c02>:0
at FreshMvvm.FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel[T] () <0x7e57b80c54 + 0x00033> in <d2b205c381d14059b4260d7482e68c02>:0
at GoTexas.App.InitNavigation () <0x7e57b426f4 + 0x00037> in <dd7679dd949e46e680e37995753481d2>:0
at GoTexas.App..ctor () <0x7e57b42600 + 0x0009f> in <dd7679dd949e46e680e37995753481d2>:0
at GoTexas.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) <0x7e54f0b75c + 0x0010f> in <a02812a7c00f4c1c87e549cce19fa824>:0
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) <0x7e598ad064 + 0x0007b> in <899f47c5cea3409e92f041348b58600b>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.7(intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at md5b9bd3a38d4378f5ce9f0aa132dfd154f.MainActivity.n_onCreate (Native Method)
  at md5b9bd3a38d4378f5ce9f0aa132dfd154f.MainActivity.onCreate (30)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7327)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7318)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1271)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3094)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3257)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1948)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7050)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

So it has something to do with FreshTinyIoC.  I just don't get why this works when running off VS 2019 in debug mode off my phone.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check if app crashes in RELEASE mode,  while setting `Linking` mode to `None`.

Comment: My linking mode is currently set to Sdk and User Assemblies.  I'll try setting it to none and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is quite simple actually you have set linking to SDK & User Assemblies which means it is linking everything, your models and every other class, anything that does not have a reference will be collected and removed for better understanding you can check my blog which has an entire section on how to work with Linking:

https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/reducing-the-app-size-in-xamarin-deep-dive-7ddc9cb12688

As of now, I would suggest you can check `Link SDK Assemblies` for now and then you can Link everything as that takes a little time

Goodluck, Feel free to get back in case of queries

Comment: My main problem seems that I was using the R8 compiler instead of Proguard.  Once I switched it was much more stable.  R8 really seems to have many issues at this time.

Comment: Well r8 still has some fixes but I would recommend it over Proguard, in any case goodluck